# Anyway to secure this JavaScript request to PHP - (Is impossible)?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I need to access this php with JavaScript. I have this php with secure access by so many ways: only for my own ip, only for my domain, direct access not allowed, secured by htaccess an we know so many other ways to secure this.

And now i have this JavaScript, then you can access this JavaScript and get data from my database. And you can do it like a monster... you can put a bot to send #input1 and get all my data.

I tried to find a solution for more than 14 hours, and read many posts, sites but no luck. NO Way. OHHH MY GOD, is this possible?

Here a part of my code: JavaScript

```
$.getScript("http://www.domain.com/getdata.php?data="+$("#input1").val(), function(){
    if (resultData["field2"] != '') {
        $("#input2").val(unescape(resultData["field2"]));
        $("#input3").val(unescape(resultData["field3"]));
    }   
});
```

And PHP

```
header('content-type: application/json; charset: utf-8');

// here my get mysql connection and query.... where field1 = #input1

if ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
    echo "var resultData = {
        'field2'    : '" . $row['field2'] . "',
        'field3'    : '" . $row['field3'] . "',
    }";
}
```

I don't believe we have no solution for this! Lost my day by trying to protect this!

I need to protect this only for who is browsing my website, o maybe per domain, or per requests =/

No Way!

Comment: Are the site users authenticated?

Comment: This has nothing to do with JavaScript. Everybody could send any requests to your server, he doesn't even need a browser for that.

Comment: First off, make it harder to find the script. Base64 encode `http://www.domain.com/getdata.php?data=` and then use `atob("Base64 ENCODED URL HERE")`

Comment: As far as security is concerned, encoding is no better than plain text.

Comment: Requiring basic HTTP Auth for both your website and that PHP script (via `htaccess` or else) should solve your issue, shouldn't it?

Comment: As an aside, why are you using _$.getScript()_ as a data retrieval mechanism? And having done that, why is your PHP setting _content-type:application/json_ when in fact it does not return json?

Comment: We have no users, no authentication needed to access this page. It's only a form with automatic population other fields. I just don't wants to have anyone doing a hard job to the database server! And other thing is... if we have authenticated users, they got access for all too? This is the problem!

Comment: Lol. I was just using json, because im not a pro with javascript, then i got this ready to use code and it work like i wants. But... no way to secure!

Comment: @FcbInfo As the others have pointed out, you don't need a browser to attack your server. `you can put a bot to send #input1 and get all my data.` - exactly, that's how HTTP communication works...and it doesn't need a browser.

Comment: its easy... its called ssl

Comment: @Orangepill That just encrypts data in the communication between the browser and server, it doesn't encrypt anything on the page; it doesn't manage traffic, which is what the OP is talking about

Comment: Anything the browser can do, a user can do. The proper way to secure something is to authenticate them and validate on the server that a user has permission to do what they are attempting. Or if the service is public, validate on the server that a public user is allowed to do what they are attempting.

Comment: JavasCript call to php <-- It's Ajax? Or with Ajax we have other tools? Other codes like ASP or Java, can do this with security?

Comment: Wow........ omg. Try Try Try AND TRY. The big solution, im very happy now!

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7953714/php-help-secure-filter-ajax-calls

Answer (score 1):

Set a session variable in your regular web pages, and have the getdata.php script check for the session variable before returning any data.

Comment: and ssl and and secure cookies.

Comment: Well... ssl will work for nothing on this case! You are mistaken or misread the post! But the session... i'm going to try that now!

Answer (score 1):

> We have no authentication for users. I just don't wants to have anyone doing a hard job to the database server!

Then use [rate limiting](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/02/rate-limiting-and-velocity-checking.html), and maybe some time/size limits on your SQL queries. No need for "securing access to the page".

Answer (score 0):

After a good night of sleep, my brain can think better! And i think in pass some md5 code on the url of javascript. And then i have found it:

[Thanks to rmorero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7953714/php-help-secure-filter-ajax-calls)

YEEEEEEEEEAAAAAAAHHHHHHHHHHH!!!! Is it!

On the source file that call js:

```
$secret ="ABC1232";

$item = array(
  "time"=>time(),
  "token_id"=>"<page_url>"
);

$signed = base64_encode(hash_hmac("sha256",json_encode($item),$secret));
$item = base64_encode(json_encode($item));

$ajax_url = "myscript.php?signed=$signed&item=$item";
```

On my case im gonna use this:

```
getdata.php?signed=<? echo php $signed ?>&amp;item<?php echo $item ?>&amp;data="+$("#input1").val()
```

On the php file, that connect to your mysql or other thing:

```
$item = json_decode(base64_decode($_REQUEST["item"]));

$timeout = 3600;

if($item->time < (time()-$timeout)){
  die("Invalid token - timeout");
}

if($item->token_id !== "<page_url>"){
  die("Invalid token - page url");
}

$secret ="ABC1232";
$valid = ($_REQUEST["signed"] === base64_encode(hash_hmac("sha256",json_encode($item),$secret));

if(!$valid){
  die("Invalid token");
}
```

I just didn't tested, but im sure, it will work like a monster =)

The big solution is that... When you have a problem like this, get out of the computer and put your brain to think! And, this is **the SOLUTION**:

***Pass something in the url of javascript, and we have a lot of ways to do it secure.***

Now, im gonna try to do something to use POST instead of GET =)

Thank you guys for try to help.